# Change the "Select" text of a select input

Tags: jquery, forms

I would like to change the `null` value of a select input to show the user that something is happening in the background.

By `null` value option I mean the first option that is selected:

```
<option value="">Select</option>
```

The "Select" is the text I'd like to (attempt) to change to say something else.

[Here is a link to a JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqosrrcm/) to show what I'm trying to do.

I thought perhaps I could change the value:

```
$('#colors').text('Loading Colors');
```

Or, perhaps I just need to create an option with a value of `loading` at the end and have it say "Loading"

```
<option value="loading">Loading Colors</option>
```

Then just select that option while the ajax is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All answers are correct...

I will show how i do every time i need something like this...

I prefer remove all options and append one saying that is loading.. I do this, because if you fill your select with others options after your ajax request, and change it again, if you dont remove the options, they will chain...

I do something like this:

```
$('#colors option').remove();
$('#colors').append("<option>Loading...</option>");
```

Finddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bqosrrcm/4/

Comment: The select is "empty" by default, I have an ajax request that populates the values based on what the previous select value is. I think this approach will work best for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand your question, but if what you want to do is change the text of the first option of the select, you need to target the `option` and not the `select` itself.

Your code edited :

```
$('#colors option').text('Loading Colors');
```

And the edited fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bqosrrcm/1/

**Note** : The code above will affect all the `option`of the `select`element, in this case it's not a problem since there is only one option, but you will have to edit the code if you want to target only one.

Comment: Thank you for the remark, I already edited my answer while you were typing!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access to the option with value "" then do this using selector `#colors option[value=""]`

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bqosrrcm/2/